# Get amount of rows returned by using a INTO OUTFILE query?

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I am wanting to get the amount of rows returned when using a `INTO OUTFILE` query.

However, using `mysql_num_rows()` produces an error & I don't want to use anything that will result in the data being stored in the dataset such as COUNT(). Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

after you run the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` you should get the number of rows returned.

[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

if you're doing this in php there's the `mysql_num_rows()` command that wraps this functionality.

Comment: Yeah... using php but using mysql_num_rows() produced an error. Thanks - I will give the found rows a try.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment the above (found_rows) response, but I wanted to (for anyone that could come here) that this is not reliable in replication installations:

From mysql doc:

Important
FOUND_ROWS() is not replicated reliably, and should not be used with databases that are to be replicated.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

I think this limitation is important

Saludos